# Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS - Syncronizing changes to TTL

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, ttl

I apologize if this has been asked.  My searches have not been successful.

If I have 2 DNS servers in my Domain and add an A record to 1 server, that record is successfully propagated to the second server.

If, however, I edit the TTL for a specific A record, that new TTL value does not appear to replicate to the other DNS server.  ex: An A record is created with TTL of 1 day.  I later change that TTL to 15min, the second DNS server appears to retain the TTL of 1 day.

I attempted to force the update via "Reload" (which could potentially do something other than what I think . . . )

Does anyone know if TTL updates in records propagate?  Any info on what I'm missing is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possibly related to the issue in the linked KB? (Basically, TTL values being incorrectly fetched from the cache with Server 2008 RS DNS servers.) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2712740

Comment: Hi @HopelessN00b. Sorry for the loooong delay, I didn't realize that I don't have email alerts active.  Unfortunately I don't think this applies.  If I log into server A and using the DNS plugin to query the local DNS I receive one value.  If I login to server B and use the plugin to view Server B's TTL I see a different value.  This whole mess may be re. my ignorance on how syncing occurs and if/how TTL values are pushed between DNS servers.  If there is any authoritative documentation (no luck in my searches) it may just contain the answer I need.

Comment: Is this an AD integrated zone?

Comment: Yes. Replication is set to All "DNS servers in this forest", Dynamic updates are set to "Secure Only".

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro the scenario you are describing. In AD integrated zones, each DNS record is stored in a partition (in your case, `ForestDNSZones`) under `DC=RECORDNAME,DC=ZONENAME,CN=MicrosoftDNS`. The record data is stored in that object's `dnsRecord` attribute. The TTL is stored as bytes 13-16, along with the other data. AD integrated zones reload their zones from AD every three minutes by default. Are you certain you are not being a little impatient? ;)

Comment: Hi @charleswj81, impatient? Always! :) But in this case I thought I'd given it a good amount of time. Then again, its been sometime since I've tried. With the 3 minute default in hand I will experiment a little and report back. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's amazing how many intricacies there are in AD when you start digging and troubleshooting. And don't worry, it's not just you. I do the F5 "dance" when I'm in a hurry!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they are.. but if your servers are in different AD 'sites' you might want to check your site-replication settings.